# How to configure alerts for line chart and card visual pinned on dashboard?

Tags: powerbi

I understand that alerts can only be configured on visuals that are pinned to Power BI dashboard.

I have pinned line chart and a card. But can't see any option to configure the alert. Are alerts only supported for specific visuals (and which?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a single value to compare it with your threshold, so it works with

- card visual
- gauge visual
- ...